# Flink Serialization of ZonedDateTime

Tags: scala, apache-flink, zoneddatetime

I have to work with time zones and nano second time resolution. I therefore use ZonedDateTime. Apparently Apache Flink does not serialize ZonedDateTime properly. It does serialize the LocalDateTime part as expected, however, it forgets to handle the time zone.

When I log for example a zoned date inside a Flink stream map function I always get something like

```
 2018-03-01T04:10:30.773471918null
```

Whereas on data inception I get the proper zone

```
 2018-03-01T04:10:30.773471918-05:00
```

The null refers to the zone. Later of course I get a null pointer exception as I have to use proper time compare, which needs the zone.

How can I fix that easiest? Thanks for a reply.

Comment: I use the timeforscala  library to get some convenience https://github.com/johanandren/timeforscala, can this be an issue?

Comment: FWIW this issue is present without timeforscala as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74339269/offsetdatetime-loses-zoneid-when-windowed-in-flink-1-15-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not fully understand why it does not pick up a serializer. This solution at least works: I implemented a Kryo serializer for ZonedDateTime

```
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.{Input, Output}
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.{Kryo, Serializer}
import com.markatta.timeforscala.ZonedDateTime

class ZonedDateTimeSerializer extends Serializer[ZonedDateTime] {
  setImmutable(true)

  override def write(kryo: Kryo, out: Output, obj: ZonedDateTime): Unit = {
    ZonedDateTimeSerializer.write(out, obj)
  }

  override def read(kryo: Kryo, in: Input, `type`: Class[ZonedDateTime]): ZonedDateTime = {
    ZonedDateTimeSerializer.read(in)
  }
}

object ZonedDateTimeSerializer {
  def write(out: Output, obj: ZonedDateTime): Unit = {
    LocalDateSerializer.write(out, obj.toLocalDate)
    LocalTimeSerializer.write(out, obj.toLocalTime)
    ZoneIdSerializer.write(out, obj.getZone)
  }

  def  read(in: Input): ZonedDateTime = {
    val date = LocalDateSerializer.read(in)
    val time = LocalTimeSerializer.read(in)
    val zone = ZoneIdSerializer.read(in)
    ZonedDateTime(date, time, zone)
  }
}
```

I took the implementation from the newest implementation [Kyro](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/serializers/TimeSerializers.java).
Then I registered it as follows:

```
    env.getConfig.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(classOf[ZonedDateTime], classOf[ZonedDateTimeSerializer])
```

This seems to fix the problem. Not sure if it comes from the fact that I use timesforscala, but I want to use this library because it adds important additions I depend on. Comments welcome.