# OffsetDateTime Loses ZoneId when Windowed in Flink 1.15.2

Tags: scala, apache-flink

When `java.time.OffsetDateTime` objects are passed to a `ProcessWindowFunction`, their `offset.id` fields seem to be coming as `null`. Since their `offset.totalSeconds` fields are set correctly, this does not lose information, but their `toString` representations include `null`s as the offset.

This is also the case if the `OffsetDateTime`'s are wrapped inside case classes.

[image: breakpoint frame]

Here is the minimal code to reproduce:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.{SerializableTimestampAssigner, WatermarkStrategy}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.EventTimeSessionWindows
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.ProcessWindowFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector
import java.time.{Duration, OffsetDateTime, ZoneOffset}

object TimeZoneTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val timestampTexts = List(
      "2022-10-31T09:56:31.828+03:00",
      "2022-10-31T09:56:32.828+03:00",
      "2022-10-31T09:56:33.828+03:00",
      "2022-10-31T09:56:30.828+03:00",
      "2022-10-31T09:56:25.828+03:00",
      "2022-10-31T10:00:25.828+03:00",
      "2022-10-31T10:02:25.828+03:00",
      "2022-10-31T11:02:25.828+03:00"
    )

    val input: DataStream[String] = env.fromCollection(timestampTexts)

    val strategy: WatermarkStrategy[OffsetDateTime] = WatermarkStrategy
        .forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
        .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner[OffsetDateTime] {
          override def extractTimestamp(element: OffsetDateTime, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = {
            element.toInstant.toEpochMilli
          }
        })

    val result: DataStream[OffsetDateTime] = input
        .map(line => OffsetDateTime.parse(line))
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(strategy)
        .keyBy(_.getYear)
        .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.minutes(10)))
        .process(new ODTProcessFunction)
    
    result.print()
    env.execute()
  }
}

class ODTProcessFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction[OffsetDateTime, OffsetDateTime, Int, TimeWindow] {
  override def process(key: Int, context: Context, elements: Iterable[OffsetDateTime], out: Collector[OffsetDateTime]): Unit = {
    elements.toList.sorted.foreach(out.collect)
  }
}
```

**My question is: Am I doing something wrong?**

I've found a workaround by simply reconstructing the OffsetDateTime from its totalSeconds at a later step like this:

```
    val resultCorrected: DataStream[OffsetDateTime] = result
        .map(offsetDT => offsetDT.toInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(offsetDT.getOffset.getTotalSeconds)))
```

Is this workaround OK?